# Sitecore 8.1 Lucene not updating - how to indentify if index has been fullly built?

Tags: azure, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

We are using Sitecore 8.1 with LUCENE search provider, 1 CM and 2x CDs. The solution is hosted in Azure Web Apps.

We noticed that when content author publishes or updates the article, the changes is seen my some users/browsers and not for others.

I suspect this is due to index not being built on one of CDs (as history engine is not enabled). In the past I could troubleshoot this by RDP to Azure Web Role VM or similar and analyse the lunene index files data time.

Above is not possible with WEB APP as you can't RDP or FTP to specific instances.

So..

1. Is there a way in Sitecore to find out whether index has been 100% built for N number of CDs?
2. Is it true that History Engine MUST be turned on if we have more than 1 CDs?
3. If there are N (where N > 1) number of CDs, does one of the CD gets rebuilt instantly after publish end? This is what we have noticed and it confuses me.
4. Any reason why History Engine section might be missing out of box?

Thanks.

Comment: The important thing is that event queues must be enabled. This is how an event one server can be triggered and handled on another server. http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2010/07/introducing-the-sitecore-event-queue.aspx

Comment: Yep, it's enabled definitely.

Comment: Is it the search index that doesn't seem to be updating across both CD's or is it the actual page renderings?   If it is the renderings, and you aren't using search indexes in the code, could be a cache clearing issue.

Comment: @NilPun Please see if my answer helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't know.
2. My understanding that you need to have History Engine "on" if you have *ANY* CDs.
3. The combined instance (that has CM and CD on the same instance) *does not need* a History Engine as it gets updated *instantly*.
4. I would expect it to be missing, as the default installation is *not intended for scaling*. Also, I would mention, that you need all your CD instances *that you publish to* explicitly listed in a web.config (or added through *Include*). Please see this post from Alen Pelin: http://blog.alen.pw/2012/06/lucene-index-isnt-updated-on-cd.html